# Android game stutters; gc under control and frame dropping in place of Thread.sleep

Tags: android, canvas, frame-rate, game-loop

I'm facing the quite famous issue (for newbies like me) of game stuttering. It happens almost continuosly and I can't find the root cause. 
I already found issues related to object creation and gc activity thanks to memory monitor of Android Studio and now they are solved. 
Thanks to some answers found here on the site, I substituted the approach of Thread.sleep to control the frame rate with a frame dropping-like logic to avoid unresponsiveness due to os schedule.
Moreover, I noticed that switching to "Performance" on my Xiaomi MI 4, so with a stable and high processor frequency, it runs smoothly; this let me think of "unexpected" picks on the processor load. Sadly, lowering the target frame rate to 30 doens't change anything.

I would like to begin showing the main loop that includes the above mentioned logic of frame-dropping:

```
private static final float TARGET_FPS=60;

private final SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;

private Paint mBackgroundPaint;

boolean  mIsOnRun;

/**
 * This is the main nucleus of our program.
 * From here will be called all the method that are associated with the display in GameEngine object
 * */
@Override
public void run()
{
    long currTime, lastFrameTime=0;
    float nFrameTot=1, nUpdateTot=1;
    float totalRenderTime=0.002f, totalUpdateTime=0.002f;
    float estimatedFrameRenderTime=0.002f, estimatedUpdateTime;

    //Looping until the boolean is false
    while (mIsOnRun)
    {
        currTime=System.nanoTime();

        //Updates the game objects business logic
        AppConstants.getEngine().update();

        if ((nUpdateTot + 1) > Float.MAX_VALUE || (totalUpdateTime + 0.002f) > Float.MAX_VALUE) {
            nUpdateTot=1;
            totalUpdateTime=0.002f;
        }
        nUpdateTot++;

        totalUpdateTime=totalUpdateTime + ((System.nanoTime() - currTime) / 1000000000f);
        estimatedUpdateTime = totalUpdateTime / nUpdateTot;

        currTime=System.nanoTime();

        if ((currTime - lastFrameTime)/1000000000f > (1/TARGET_FPS)-estimatedFrameRenderTime-estimatedUpdateTime) {

            lastFrameTime=currTime;

            //locking the canvas
            Canvas canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);

            if (canvas != null)
            {
                //Clears the screen with black paint and draws object on the canvas
                synchronized (mSurfaceHolder)
                {
                    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), mBackgroundPaint);
                    AppConstants.getEngine().draw(canvas);
                }

                //unlocking the Canvas
                mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }

            nFrame++;

            if ((nFrameTot + 1) > Float.MAX_VALUE || (totalRenderTime + 0.002f) > Float.MAX_VALUE) {
                nFrameTot=1;
                totalRenderTime=0.002f;
            }
            nFrameTot++;

            totalRenderTime=totalRenderTime + ((System.nanoTime() - lastFrameTime) / 1000000000f);
            estimatedFrameRenderTime = totalRenderTime / nFrameTot;

        }
    }
}
```

Now, speaking of what the game does, it's a card game and a color-filled background and at most 16 bitmaps at a time are drawn; the only "animations" are these bitmaps moving around. 
I honestly don't know whether I might be doing something easy in a stupid way and would be happy to share more code snippets if it can help you understand more on my problem.

Thank you for any time you lose on this!